# Can’t configure TP-Link Archer C60 Wi-Fi router as WDS

Tags: router, wds

I am trying to configure my Archer C60 router as WDS.
My internet modem IP address is 192.168.25.1, so I changed the router IP address to 192.168.25.2. I disabled DHCP and enabled WDS with my modem Wi-Fi SSID and password.
The modem says the router is conected to it, the router says WDS is running, however, I can’t get internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Check whether you can get internet when connect to our router’s network. If not, it is suggested to power cycle the main root AP and our router and try the internet again.The two devices could be incompatible in WDS bridge mode if internet still does not work after power cycling them." - - http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-227.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device, you are trying to connect to the WDS receives an IP address, if it doesn't you need to enable DHCP and configure a second subnet.
Even with a wired wifi repeater, I need to have the DHCP enabled, which is not ideal but works, plus you need to configure another subnet due to the limitation of overlapping IP addresses within the firmware on the device ):

So for your main network:

```
- IP: 192.168.25.1/24
- SSID: xxx
- PW: 1234
```

Extender:

```
- SSID: xxx
- PW: 1234
- WAN Port IP: 192.168.25.2/24 (Static or Dynamic doesn't matter, picks up main modems DHCP)
- LAN Port IP: 192.168.26.1/24
- DHCP: 192.168.26.2-254/24   
- Default GW: 192.168.26.1
- DNS: 192.168.26.1
```

Hope this helps.

Here is the manual just in-case you haven't seen it:
http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/Archer_C60(EU)_V1_UG.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please check your cables, sometimes people forget and put cable from primary modem/router to wan socket on secondary router. You should have connected cable from primary modem/router to one of LAN sockets on your secondary router. Then make 100% sure that DHCP is running only on your primary modem/router sometimes there is need to check that specifically for LAN and WiFi.